# wpdb result arrray inside an array

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to run a database query as below:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = 'select * from ';
$query .= $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'fxdescription ';
$query .= 'where id= '.$id;
$currency = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $query ), ARRAY_A );
```

The result of doing print_r($currency) is as below:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => EUR [name] => Euro [description] => [format] => direct ) 
)
```

The question is - is the above result normal, as the result is an array inside an array, and to access the data I have to use `$currency['0']['code']`, in place of `$currency['code']`?

Comment: Side note: I do like this `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $currency, true) . '</pre>'` to get an easier to read output.

Answer (score 1):

1. its normal for get_results method
2. you can use [get_row](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row) method to get only one row.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried [get_row](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row) method, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, the default output type of `get_results` is object, but you've set it to associative arrays.

Yes, you'll need to use `$currency[0]['code']`, or you could use

```
foreach ( $currency as $c ) {
    echo $c['code']; // can now be accessed
}
```